# How to install rustfmt with the release of Rust 1.32?

Tags: macos, rust

I'm on macOS Mojave. I've used Rust in the past and rustfmt has always worked, but I can no longer download rustfmt.

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.32.0 (9fda7c223 2019-01-16)

$ rustup component add rustfmt
error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin' does not contain component 'rustfmt' for target 'x86_64-apple-darwin'
```

Is there some other command that I need to execute?

Comment: Seems a darwin platform issue. Cannot reproduce on `stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

Comment: Could not reproduce with `rustup 1.16.0 (beab5ac2b 2018-12-06)` on macOS Mojovae. If you have not updated `rustup`, could you please try with the latest `rustup`? You can update it by running `rustup self update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try these commands:

```
rustup toolchain remove stable && rustup toolchain add stable
```

OR

```
rustup toolchain remove stable && rustup toolchain install stable
```

It can help in several cases after compiler version updates, like **rustfmt**, **clippy**, or other Rust components.